# ireport : getting error while updating jrxml to jasper server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Getting error 1-0 while updating jrxml file to jasperserver (5.6.0) from ireport 5.1.0

Tried a work around by un-commenting the property,as mentioned in jasper community
--server not restarted after the change

```
<parameter name="attachments.Directory" value="attachments"></parameter>
```

checked the space/memory in server installed location,enough disk space is available.

but same error persists while updating the jrxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was with disk space only,but space utilization shown while running 'df -h',

temp folder in tomcat was about 457MiB.
After deleting the contents ,was able to update the jrxml to jasper server repository.